# ^M (ctrl+M) character is a part of string but java get end of line

Tags: java, readfile, control-characters

i have a log file that each line is a row of database and i want insert it into database. in value of password field there is ^M (ctrl+M) character and it is not end of line but when java scanner arrive it take the remaining characters of the line new line how can i solve.note that it i need it and don't want to remove it

Comment: don't use a `Scanner` to read the file.

Comment: so how to read the file?

Comment: You can use a `FileReader` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use BufferedReader with a FileReader instead of Scanner.
or you can read the file with the respective encoding type i,e.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("LogFile.txt"), "utf-8");
```